# Fade in and out image with preloader

Tags: jquery

I have a loader that fades in and fades out when the page is fully loaded. How would I make the image fade in and then fade out during this transition? So I am looking for the image to fade in the fade out then the pre-loader fades out.

So the transitions occurs like

**Pre-loader background > Image fades in > Image fade out > Pre-loader background fades out**

A similar effect as the loader [here](http://grovemade.com/).

I apologise if this is fairly simple. Currently the pre-loader and image fade in at the same time using

```
<div class="loader-container">
    <img src="image.png" alt="Image">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        jQuery(".loader-container").delay(500).fadeOut("1000");
    });
// ]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the callbacks of the jQuery animations:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#loader-image").fadeIn(500, function(){
        jQuery("#loader-image").delay(500).fadeOut(1000, function(){
            jQuery(".loader-container").fadeOut(2000);
        });
    });
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2kUSw/